# Writing a WinRT component using WRL

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have been using the project template called "Windows Runtime Component" that ships with VS2012 in order to create a C++/CX based WinRT component.

I now wish to do the same thing without using C++/CX but through WRL.  When I do this, there are some things (referencing, automatic packaging with the main app project, Winmd-based intellisense etc.) that don't work in VS2012.  How can I make sure that I can use WRL in my component project and still get the full IDE experience like I get with C++/CX based template?

Comment: What would be the purpose of avoiding C++/CX for such scenario?

Comment: People have their reasons. The idea is that there is a choice.

Comment: I'm not questioning it as being something not worth doing. I am simply curious why would people have such a reason. You don't have to say if you can't.

Comment: The idea is not to avoid C++/CX but just in case someone has a preference for WRL.  One reason I have heard people say is to not use non-standard language extensions.  Another reason is to avoid exceptions in their internal code.

Comment: But WRL isn't a standard library is it? So if you used it you would be using non-standard library anyway. C++/CX should only be used for that WinRT Component interface layer anyway, so an actual library would remain the same, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Visual Studio project template for WRL components here:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/346e6fbc-6508-43c8-af7f-9a922bb57128

This achieves a similar result both at design-time and at runtime as does the C++/CX based project template.

Comment: Hi Raman, the link is broken! Actually it states: " 
This item is not yet published.
If you are the owner of this project, please sign in with the appropriate account. "